# SQL Query to get difference between date parameter and calculate the week

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When we pass the start date and end date in the parameter,  I have to calculate the difference and if the difference comes as 7 then it should return 1,
if 14 then 2 and if 21 then 3 so on and so forth.

```
select person_number,
amount * 
case when( :p_to_date - :p_from_date) =6
then 1
else ( :p_to_date - :p_from_date) >6 and  ( :p_to_date - :p_from_date) <=14 
then 2
else ( :p_to_date - :p_from_date) >14 and  ( :p_to_date - :p_from_date) <=21
then 3
else ( :p_to_date - :p_from_date) >21 and  ( :p_to_date - :p_from_date) <=28 
then 4
end as week
from 
per_all_people_F papf
```

Is the above logic correct ?

Comment: At least the last case is wrong. How can something be `> 28` and `<= 28` at the same time? That should probably be `> 21`. Same for `> 21` and  `<=21`. That should probably be `> 14` and `<= 21`. Futhermore, your code is contradicting your text. You explicitely say "*if the difference comes as 7 then it should return 1*", yet you return `1` only when the difference `= 6`. And what happens if the difference is less then `6` or greater than `28`? You should have a return value for that cases too.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you may want to count "weeks" (seven day periods)? Maybe `ceil((:p_to_date - :p_from_date) / 7)` or something similar is what you actually want? [Edit] the question and describe the logic you want *precisely*, not just by a few examples that leave ambiguities. (And a code that doesn't implement it is not helpful either.)

Comment: @derpirscher - Thanks for correcting !

Comment: You want `floor()` rather than a ceiling function. With positive numbers you can just use simple integer division.

Comment: @shawnt00: Depends on the logic. `floor()` if they want to count weeks that fully past, `ceil()` if they want to count weeks that were "touched". But who knows other than the OP, who didn't tell us their logic...

Comment: Yeah, there's major inconsistency between the narrative and the attempt. Considering how difficult it usually is to get useful clarification I should probably just stop doing this.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a formula rather than getting lost in a labyrinth of CASE WHEN expressions?

this one seems to work:

```
WITH
-- some test data in a Common Table Expression named "indata" ...
indata(from_dt,to_dt) AS (
            SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-01' FROM dual                                                                                                                                                                           
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-02' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-03' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-04' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-05' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-06' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-07' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-08' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-09' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-10' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-11' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-12' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-13' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-14' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-15' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-16' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-17' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-18' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-19' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-20' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-21' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',DATE '2022-01-22' FROM dual
)
SELECT
  to_dt
, to_dt - from_dt AS date_diff
, CAST(FLOOR((to_dt - from_dt) / 7) + 1 AS NUMBER(5)) AS ora_week_diff
FROM indata;
-- out    to_dt    | date_diff | ora_week_diff 
-- out ------------+-----------+---------------
-- out  2022-01-01 |         0 |             1
-- out  2022-01-02 |         1 |             1
-- out  2022-01-03 |         2 |             1
-- out  2022-01-04 |         3 |             1
-- out  2022-01-05 |         4 |             1
-- out  2022-01-06 |         5 |             1
-- out  2022-01-07 |         6 |             1
-- out  2022-01-08 |         7 |             2
-- out  2022-01-09 |         8 |             2
-- out  2022-01-10 |         9 |             2
-- out  2022-01-11 |        10 |             2
-- out  2022-01-12 |        11 |             2
-- out  2022-01-13 |        12 |             2
-- out  2022-01-14 |        13 |             2
-- out  2022-01-15 |        14 |             3
-- out  2022-01-16 |        15 |             3
-- out  2022-01-17 |        16 |             3
-- out  2022-01-18 |        17 |             3
-- out  2022-01-19 |        18 |             3
-- out  2022-01-20 |        19 |             3
-- out  2022-01-21 |        20 |             3
-- out  2022-01-22 |        21 |             4
```

Comment: Why the CASTs - just `FLOOR((to_dt - from_dt) / 7) + 1` would give the same result?

Comment: I am very picky when it comes to data types. `FLOOR()` returns a double `FLOAT`. And: an Oracle `DATE` is actually a DATETIME, so subtracting a DATETIME from a DATETIME could return a float, not an integer. And `FLOOR(15 / 7)` will be a `FLOAT`. You will see that I edited my answer, finding out that casting the date subtraction does not make a difference - so I removed it. But if a numeric value can only return whole integers, I'd like the result to be as close to an integer as Oracle allows ...

Comment: I can't argue with being picky, but it doesn't seem to change anything here - either way the caller gets a 2-byte `NUMBER` back. `FLOOR` [returns an integer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FLOOR.html) as "the same data type as the numeric data type of the argument"; but 15/7 is still a `NUMBER` rather than the subtype `FLOAT`. (Though it's hard to tell the difference - they're both internal type 2, e.g. in dump output, [but it would lose precision as `FLOAT`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d68c408c1a13a6660d16b2cf7839c5ec)). Anyway...